# characteristic function of exponential distribution, real integral with complex numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis

While I was reading calculation of characteristic function for exponential distribution I saw these equalities:

$\int_0^{\infty} e^{itx}  \lambda e^{-\lambda x } dx = \frac{\lambda}{it - \lambda} e^{(it - \lambda)x}\bigg|_0^{\infty} = \frac{\lambda}{ \lambda- it}$

How is this integral evaluated at infinity? Plugging for $x$ bigger and bigger numbers to $(it-\lambda)x$ gives complex number and at infinity it has to equal $-\infty$ (if the last equation is right). How from complex numbers we get $-\infty$ at the limit?

Answer (score 1):

$|e^{(it-x)}|=e^{-x}\to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, so $e^{(it-x)}$ also tends to $0$.